# Using APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR vs RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

Can someone explain to me the difference between using `APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR` vs `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`? What are some drawback of using one vs the other, if any? Or what are the advantages? Is rendering HTML code inside the error message the only advantage of `APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR`? Both seem to display an error message at the top of the page. The only difference, besides rendering HTML, I see is that with APEX_ERROR I can specify the location of the error displayed. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the result looks similar, they are different things with different purposes, so neither has any advantages or drawbacks.

`APEX_ERROR.add_error` is an *APEX* API call to allow you to programmatically inject error messages onto the stack for reporting to the user.

`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is a *PL/SQL* command to trigger a custom *exception* (in hindsight it should probably have been called `RAISE_APPLICATION_EXCEPTION` to avoid confusion...). Like any PL/SQL exception, if your PL/SQL code doesn't handle it or suppress it, APEX will simply show it to the user like any other error message.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that in the latest APEX versions RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR in a page process does not display for end users.  The error text is only visible to developers.  Users see a generic contact support with debug id.